# Fetching results before join Zend

Tags: mysql, join, zend-framework

I have two tables for example "first" and "second". I had to limit first table data to 10 and then join the second table. Both are very large. I joined them and then apply limit after the join. And then fetched the results.

```
    $select = $db->select();

    $select->from(array("f"=>'first'),'*')

           ->join(array("s"=>'second'),'f.id= s.id','*')

           -> where("f.state = active")

           ->order('f.cost DESC')

           ->limit(10,20);

   $res = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

This above query is taking lot of time. Is there any way to fetch results before and then join to reduce the query time? How to do in ZEND

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch both tables with the limits, that would give you two Zend_Db_Table_Rowset and then, you could use PHP array functions to "join" them.

I think that this function is quite similar to an inner join but in arrays: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-uintersect.php

```
array_uintersect($rowset1->toArray(), $rowset2->toArray(), "strcasecmp")
```

This would compare strings and do the join.

I don't know if this would really be quicker, though.

Comment: But how can i add limit on the second("second") table. It is dependent on the first("first") table limits and conditions. First limit and conditions are set on first table and then according to that join happens on second table